# search for pattern in string and echo if find it

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a following problem: I need to check if string contains any pattern string and echo the result if it does.

```
$searching_post = preg_match("/#([0-9]{3,8})/", $_POST['Description']);
```

this will return 1 if it contain pattern, but I would like to return that result instead one. So if `$_POST['Description']` contain for example #123 I want to return #123 instead 1. Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: See preg_match PhP manual -> `$matches` flag is what you're looking for.

Comment: Check out the third parameter to [preg_match](http://www.php.net/preg_match)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the manual for [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) you'll figure out that it puts the matches into a referenced variable in the 3rd parameter:

> int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )

---

> preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.

---

So the code should be something like the following:

```
$searching_post = null;
if (preg_match("/#([0-9]{3,8})/", $_POST['Description'], $matches)) {
    $searching_post = $matches[1];
}
var_dump($searching_post); //will be NULL if nothing was found
```